# app crashes when runs in small and large screens in android

Tags: android

I have been developing an app which should support multiple screen sizes. It works fine when I run that app on medium size screen(nexus 3.7), but if I run the same code using a small or large screen then the app crashes. Can anyone tell me how to solve this issue?

```
02-06 21:05:38.384: E/AndroidRuntime(331): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.deepak.alice/com.android.deepak.alice.SwipeOfLetters}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-06 21:05:38.384: E/AndroidRuntime(331): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-06 21:05:38.384: E/AndroidRuntime(331): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-06 21:05:38.384: E/AndroidRuntime(331): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to be clear:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

This means you allocate more memory than you should.
According to the screen issue I would say you are allocating a Bitmap or something else which size depends on the screen size. You should then regard using a maximum size, no matter what the actual screen size is and scale the values up.

Comment: hi michael...is there any way to eliminate this memory issue through code??

Comment: Yes. By using native allocations (c++) you do not have any restrictions. In Java this is not possible. Try generally avoiding all memory leaks and allocate only as much as absolutely neccessary.